# meta-arm-toolchain: SUPPORTED file not found

Tags: arm, embedded, yocto

I'm trying to add the arm toolchain to my yocto project but I just got this error

```
| cp: cannot stat '.../tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/external-arm-toolchain/2022.02-r0/image/local/SUPPORTED': No such file or directory
```

It comes from the `external-arm-toolchain.bb` recipe. I've checked and the `SUPPORTED` file is in the right folder (the `files` folder where the `external-arm-toolchain.bb` file is). I haven't made any modifications to the meta-arm repo. I just cloned it and changed to branch `kirkstone`. After that, I have configured my local.conf with this:

```
TCMODE = "external-arm"

EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN = ".../gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf"
```

I have added this to the `bblayers.conf`:

```
BBLAYERS += "${OEROOT}/layers/meta-arm/meta-arm-toolchain"
```

And that's it, I think. Have I missed any steps?

UPDATE: Here is the complete output from yocto:

```
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: external-arm-toolchain-2022.02-r0 do_stash_locale: ExecutionError('.../tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/external-arm-toolchain/2022.02-r0/temp/run.do_stash_locale.449', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: .../tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/external-arm-toolchain/2022.02-r0/temp/log.do_stash_locale.449
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function sstate_task_prefunc
| DEBUG: Python function sstate_task_prefunc finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_stash_locale
| cp: cannot stat '.../tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/external-arm-toolchain/2022.02-r0/image/local/SUPPORTED': No such file or directory
| WARNING: .../tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/external-arm-toolchain/2022.02-r0/temp/run.do_stash_locale.449:165 exit 1 from 'cp -fpPR .../tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/external-arm-toolchain/2022.02-r0/image/local/SUPPORTED $dest'
| WARNING: Backtrace (BB generated script):
|     #1: do_stash_locale, .../tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/external-arm-toolchain/2022.02-r0/temp/run.do_stash_locale.449, line 165
|     #2: main, .../tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/external-arm-toolchain/2022.02-r0/temp/run.do_stash_locale.449, line 177
ERROR: Task (.../layers/meta-arm/meta-arm-toolchain/recipes-devtools/external-arm-toolchain/external-arm-toolchain.bb:do_stash_locale) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2402 tasks of which 2396 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
NOTE: Writing buildhistory took: 4 seconds

Summary: 1 task failed:
  .../layers/meta-arm/meta-arm-toolchain/recipes-devtools/external-arm-toolchain/external-arm-toolchain.bb:do_stash_locale
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Did you really create a folder with a name `...`?

Comment: @skandigraun No, that's just a placeholder, the path is a normal path, I just removed that part before posting it here.

Comment: This command seems to be generated from this line: cp -fpPR ${WORKDIR}/SUPPORTED $dest - have you change your WORKDIR variable somewhere for this recipe? (Note that this script is part of poky, not meta-arm)

Comment: @skandigraun I haven't changed WORKDIR. I have also been looking for that "image/local" part in the folder but nothing comes up. I have also tried building an image with a default configuration in a default poky/yocto, and it built with the toolchain just fine. There must be something somewhere in one of our configuration files that appends hat string in this case.

Comment: @skandigraun I kept investigating and it seems like someone in my team, some time ago, made a custom glibc-package.inc which did change the WORKDIR value, and I didn't know. That was all in the end.

I've modified this file to revert the change and the toolchain is working perfectly now.